# Type of zeros of $\cos(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Are the zeros of $cos(z)$ simple or multiple? How to find out the integer k so that $\cos(z)=(z-a)^kf(z)$ where a is a zero of the $\cos(z)$ ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $z=x+iy$, then
$$
\cos(z) = \cos(x)\cosh(y) - i\sin(x)\sinh(y)
$$
If $\cos(z) = 0$, then (since $\cosh(y) \geq 1$), it follows that $\cos(x) = 0$, whence
$$
x = \pm (2n-1)\pi/2
$$
But then $\sin(x) \neq 0$, and so $\sinh(y) = 0$, and so $y=0$.

So the zeroes of $\cos(z)$ are
$$
z = \pm (2n-1)\pi/2
$$

Now, if $z$ is a multiple zero of $\cos(z)$, then what happens to the derivative of $\cos(z)$ are that point?

Comment: The derivate vanishes at that point, but the derivate is $-\sin(z)$ which has no common zero with $\cos(z)$, thank you!

Comment: @ Mr. Vaidyanathan How to find $f(z)$ here?

Comment: @Samprity : If $g(z) = (z-a)f(z)$, then $f(z) = g(z)/(z-a)$ right?

Comment: @ Mr. Vaidyanathan So here it is $\cos(z)/(z-a)$, and $a$ is a removable singularity of $f(z)$. Anything else?